# Запрос при определенном условии

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Есть запроc mysql

```
      SELECT datacenter.id, avatar, text, id_finish, datacenter.name, datacenter.surname  
   FROM massage JOIN datacenter 
   ON datacenter.id = massage.id_start 
  WHERE massage.id_finish = '$id'
```

Как сделать, что-бы данные с поля text брались не при

```
   WHERE massage.id_finish = '$id'
```

а при

```
    WHERE massage.id_start = '$id'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT datacenter.id, avatar, dc.text, id_finish, datacenter.name, datacenter.surname  FROM massage 
JOIN datacenter as dc ON datacenter.id = massage.id_start 
WHERE massage.id_finish = '$id'
```

вы почти правильно написали :)